dropdown element added dynamically through javascript is being duplicated in the DOM
I'm adding a dropdown element to the page dynamically through javascript. I want this dropdown to  be able to change the properties displayed on a map, so I'm attempting to add the element after the map loads. The issue I'm having is that the dropdown element is rendered multiple times on the page, and additional dropdown elements are added every time I re-size the page?
Here's some pseudo-code, apologies: I'm not able to post a replicable example at the moment because this is embedded in a r2d3 framework (d3.js library in R) and that would get overly complicated.
Any thoughts as to why this is duplicating the dropdown?
//set default property for map so it knows which field to use for the map fill color  
var dropdown_val = 'ODpc'

//function that initially draws the map   
function loadMap(dropdown_val) {
  map2.on('load', function () {
    // Add source and layers, etc...

    // Create and inside the load function instead.
    addElement();
  });
}

loadMap(dropdown_val)

//this will be used to add sidebar to the page
function insertAfter(newNode, existingNode) {
  existingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, existingNode.nextSibling);
}

function addElement() {

   // create a sidebar to hold dropdown
   const sidebar = document.createElement("div");
   sidebar.className = "sidebar";
   sidebar.id = "sidebar";


  //For the dropdown: Create array of options to be added
  var array = ["2014-2022", "2022","2021","2020","2019", "2018", "2017", "2016", "2015", "2014"];
  var val_array = ["ODpc", "ODpc2022","ODpc2021","ODpc2020","ODpc2019", "ODpc2018", "ODpc2017", "ODpc2016", "ODpc2015", "ODpc2014"];

  //Create and append select list
  var selectList = document.createElement("select");
  selectList.id = "mySelect";
  selectList.className = "mySelect";


  //Create and append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = val_array[i];
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
  }

  //make legend etc.. etc...

  // Connect the event listener
  selectList.addEventListener('change', onChange);

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  // Get a reference to the parent node
  const parentDiv = document.getElementById("map_choropleth_state").parentNode;

  const mapDiv = document.getElementById("map_choropleth_state");

  //add the sidebar, which will hold the dropdown
  insertAfter(sidebar, mapDiv);

  //add the dropdown
  sidebar.appendChild(selectList);

 };

function onChange(event) {
  const dropdown_val = event.target.value;
  // Update the layers depending on the value
}

Picture here:


I would imagine your code to add the drop down is being run multiple times in the "r2d3" environment.   Add some liberal console.logs or breakpoints to determine, eg, how often the loadMap function is run

@fdomn-m thanks! I don't think it is though? The script is called exactly one time in r2d3

Put a breakpoint in addElement, you'll find out where it's being called from.

Could it be that the "framework" / "map" / "d3" is cloning the sidebar?   ie it's not in your code but somewhere else?

Resizing the page causes the map to be reloaded, which fires the handler function that you set up with your map2.on() call.
So, just add a check for the sidebar, if it is already in the DOM, then do not add it again. The if() statement in this version of your loadMap() code will do that for you:
    //function that initially draws the map
function loadMap(dropdown_val) {
    map2.on('load', function () {
        // Add source and layers, etc...
        
        // HERE is the new bit to stop screen resizing from adding another sidebar
        if( !document.getElementById("sidebar") ) {
            // Create and inside the load function instead.
            addElement();
        }
    });
}


this worked!  Thank you!  But, the element was duplicated even before the page was re-sized.  I have no idea why this would be the case.
